# MSSQL replication snapshot agent fails

Tags: sql-server, replication, linux, sql-server-2019, transactional-replication

I'm using MS SQL server 2019 on Linux. I'm trying to create a transactional replication.
The problem is that when I create a publication, the snapshot agent can not start.
Basically, I'm getting this message:
[image]

When I check under SQL agent server jobs, I see the following messages:

```
2023-03-22 01:55:25.724 Status: 0, code: 20015, text: 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.'.
2023-03-22 01:55:25.724 Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.
```

And also this:

```
2023-03-22 01:50:32.33 Connecting to Distributor 'TEST-DB1.MYDOMAIN.COM'
2023-03-22 01:50:32.81 The replication agent had encountered an exception.
2023-03-22 01:50:32.81 Source: Replication
2023-03-22 01:50:32.81 Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ConnectionFailureException
2023-03-22 01:50:32.81 Exception Message: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.
2023-03-22 01:50:32.81 Message Code: 18452
```

Here is the publication SQL in case it's needed:

```
use [testdb]
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = N'testdb', @optname = N'publish', @value = N'true'
GO
-- Adding the transactional publication
use [testdb]
exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'testdb-publication', @description = N'Transactional publication of database ''testdb'' from Publisher ''test-db1.mydomain.com''.', @sync_method = N'concurrent', @retention = 0, @allow_push = N'true', @allow_pull = N'true', @allow_anonymous = N'true', @enabled_for_internet = N'false', @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true', @compress_snapshot = N'false', @ftp_port = 21, @ftp_login = N'anonymous', @allow_subscription_copy = N'false', @add_to_active_directory = N'false', @repl_freq = N'continuous', @status = N'active', @independent_agent = N'true', @immediate_sync = N'true', @allow_sync_tran = N'false', @autogen_sync_procs = N'false', @allow_queued_tran = N'false', @allow_dts = N'false', @replicate_ddl = 1, @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'false', @enabled_for_p2p = N'false', @enabled_for_het_sub = N'false'
GO


exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'testdb-publication', @frequency_type = 1, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 0, @frequency_subday_interval = 0, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0, @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @publisher_security_mode = 1


use [testdb]
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'testdb-publication', @article = N'users', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'users', @type = N'logbased', @description = null, @creation_script = null, @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, @identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual', @destination_table = N'users', @destination_owner = N'dbo', @vertical_partition = N'false', @ins_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSins_dbousers', @del_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSdel_dbousers', @upd_cmd = N'SCALL sp_MSupd_dbousers'
GO
```

Is this some kind of bug, or am I missing something?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: No bug, "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication." Look for the 18456 in the errorlog. You're using Windows auth to connect: @publisher_security_mode = 1. Fix your windows auth issues.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Thank you for the reply. I have already added to @publisher_security_mode = 1 to `exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'testdb-publication', @frequency_type = 1, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 0, @frequency_subday_interval = 0, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0, @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @publisher_security_mode = 1
` or should I add it somewhere else? Also, the login mode is mixed.

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote. You're getting a login failed. Fix that issue.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I understand that login is failing, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. If you have any advice on what should I do or check, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would check your environment, which is using Windows Auth, as to why you're getting the login is from an untrusted domain. Typically an SPN issue, but doesn't have to be. Again, look into and fix the login failure, I don't understand how this is controversial.